# When is map of $E_{\infty}$-ring spectra etale iff certain condition is fullfilled

Tags: homotopy-theory, etale-cohomology

When is it true that a map of $E_{\infty}$-ring spectra $R \to S$ is etale (in Lurie's sense) if and only if, $\operatorname{TAQ}^R(S) = 0$ and $ \pi_*(R)\otimes_{\pi_0(R)} \pi_0(S) = \pi_*(S)$?

Comment: What is the definition of etal for ring spectra?